# Content Security Policy issue - Directus 9.24.0v

Tags: vue.js, content-security-policy, pdf-viewer, directus, .env

i am trying to display pdf file from  **directus CMS** site, but it showing error "Refused to load plugin data from 'https://eal.com/assets/7e7ec2d1-eab7-41fa-8181-e972eba1fd1e' **because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "object-src 'none'".**",

so i added the .env file itself ASSETS_CONTENT_SECURITY_POLICY_DIRECTIVES__MEDIA_SRC= "array:'self',blob:,https://*",  but still not resolved issue. any one resolve this issues?

Enviorement and Tools:

1. -9.24.0 v
   2.running through docker container
2. .env
   4.Linux Ubuntu

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace 'none' with sdga.vpanel.shakedeal.com in object-src. It seems like you are trying to modify media-src, which would not allow the content.

Comment: Actually, i used embed for displaying pdf, but now changed I frame , now it displaying